# iis isapi and asp.net,what's the relationship of them?

Tags: asp.net, iis

iis isapi and asp.net,what's the relationship of them?
eg: a request send to server,question 1 :please  describe a simple process workflow .

Q2:
did a request can be handle by asp.net engine and isapi in order? or only one can hanle the request?

Answer (score 0):

Depends which version of IIS you are referring to. 
The asp.net engine WAS invoked by the isapi before Integrated Pipeline mode existed. In classic mode (or prior to integrated pipeline) the isapi extension was invoked and used interop to call off into asp.net for the request.

Since the Integrated Pipeline is the main mode used now, check out:

http://drdobbs.com/windows/219501263

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135973.aspx